# Why doesn't my preview layer stretch over the entire view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

Im making a iPhone app with a AVFoundation camera but the camera is not scaling properly.

I think I have done a lot to make it the same size, I changed the video gravity to ResizeAspectFill and I changed the previewlayer.frame.size to self.layer.frame.size.

Why isn't my preview layer stretching over the entire view? Is it something I have typed wrong or just forgotten that I need to type out? Thanks!

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXvfp.jpg

code:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class View1: UIViewController {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer: CALayer!
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice!

    @IBOutlet weak var photoButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView:  UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        photoButton.layer.zPosition = 1
    }

    @IBAction func photoButtonpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let button = sender as UIButton
        if (button.tag == 1){
            print("Photobutton clicked")        
        }
    }

    func prepareCamera(){

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

        if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                               mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                                               position: .back).devices {

            captureDevice = availableDevices.first

            beginSession()  
        }
    }

    func beginSession(){
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)       
        } catch {  
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession){

            self.previewLayer = previewLayer

            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)

            self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
            self.previewLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds
            self.previewLayer.contentsGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            captureSession.startRunning()

            let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

            dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

            dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
                captureSession.commitConfiguration()        
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)    
        prepareCamera()    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and do: `self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds` because layers are not constrained. They take the bounds of the parent but it doesn't resize when the parent has laid out.. so you have to do it manually like that. `self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame self.previewLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds` is wrong. Don't change the bounds after setting the frame.. Setting just the frame is enough because the frame is actually the "position" plus the "bounds".

Comment: Is this all the code in the View Controller? What is this `cameraView` outlet you have before `viewDidLoad` but then never use in your code? It's coming from a storyboard, I assume... are there constraints on it?

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code and run on `iOS 10.1.1`, `iPhone6`, `XCode 8.2.1` it works.
[image: Screen shot of your workable code]

How you load `View1`? programmatically? initiate in storyboard? the `view` of `View1` might have different size with your device screen.

Comment: Thats so weird, the code was copied from another project that I made (Where it worked) and when i copied and redid everything so the projects Where the same I got this.

Comment: how you display your `View1`?

Comment: Im not really sure What you mean but I use a scroll view and view1 is a XIB file.

Comment: The problem lies in how you initiate `View` and display it.

Comment: Ok, how Can I fix it? It worked on My device before I made a new project and pasted it over

Comment: We need you post more code. Is `View1` is your initial View Controller? Or how you initiate `View1` and display it. ex `UINib.init(nibName: "your nib name", bundle: nil)`.

Comment: let V1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)

Comment: let V1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
        
        let V2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)

Comment: self.addChildViewController(V1)
        
        self.scrollPages.addSubview(V1.view)
        
        V1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        
        
        
        self.addChildViewController(V2)
        
        self.scrollPages.addSubview(V2.view)
        
        V2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

Comment: var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
        
        V2Frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
        
        V2.view.frame = V2Frame

Comment: self.scrollPages.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width,
                                              
                                              height: self.view.frame.height * 2)

Comment: im sorry i dont know why it got formatted in such a weird way but i think you can see the code :) Thanks!

Comment: You can edit your question and post more code about this because this still works.

Comment: Where you alloc your `scrollPages`? in xib? did you check the size of `scrollPages`?

Comment: that is my entire project

Comment: The scrollview(scrollPages) is in the storyboard and it is constrained to be the same height and width as the main viewcontroller and also center.

Comment: Can you show your constraint in storyboard? (edit your question)

Comment: V1.view.frame.size = self.view.frame.size

Comment: But the button is too low and not center

Comment: Hey buddy! Is there a way I can add you to a discord server and just type with you? I have a small issue

Comment: codus@codus.me :)